# arrayfunc with multiple arguments

Tags: matlab

Supposing I have the function test which takes arguments x and y.

Now, I have

```
myVector = 1:5
```

and

```
myVar = 6
```

I want to run test several times such as x takes all the values present in myVector and y is always myVar:

Ie : test(1,6) test(2,6) ... test(5,6)

my original ideas was to use arrayfunc, however, from what I see arrayfunc takes as paramters the function I want to call and a vector of values.

Any suggestions?

Dario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with an anonymous function that takes the element of `myVector` and passes it to your `test` function:

```
arrayfun(@(n) test(n,myVar), myVector)
```